# C++ Ntstrsafe.h / ntifs.h

Tags: c++

I just came back to an old code of mine and I had the following errors.

> Cannot Open Source File "Ntstrsafe.h" / Cannot Open Source File
>   "ntifs.h"

Should be an easy fix, how ever I did try to google and all I find are answears from 2004 and they don't really help.

I'm on Windows 10, with visual studio 2015 update 3.

Comment: Comment out the `#include` lines, see what does not compile. Then code alternates for those functions.

Comment: @crashmstr more or less my whole code.

Answer (score 0):

They are part of WindowsDriverKit you can dowload WDK [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit)